# Why do i get error message "Error retrieving data. Bad Gateway" while running cordova weather app in visual studio?

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova, openweathermap

When I tried to run the sample cordova weather app from

> https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-samples I get error.

Comment: what error are you getting?.

Comment: "error retrieving data.Bad Gateway" is the error message displayed in the screen.

Comment: add you enter the your key in this js file https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-samples/blob/master/weather-app/WeatherApp/www/scripts/weather.js

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly how you called the API, but I got the same error when I passed the zip code as a parameter. So I changed it to use id instead and it worked for me like this

```
 var queryString =
    'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id='
    + cityId+ ',us&appid=' + OpenWeatherAppKey + '&units=imperial';
```

you can try this for example for New York city:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=5128581,us&appid=yourkey&units=imperial

you can get the id from this site for example New-york-city:

http://www.geonames.org/5128581/new-york-city.html

openweathermap also provides alternative ways to get the weather using id,zip code ,lat long , ...etc

check [this](http://openweathermap.org/current)